# ControlsFX RangeSlider Can't be disabled

Tags: java, javafx, controlsfx

I am using `ControlsFX 8.40.9` and latest JDK 1.8.0_51
I can't set the `RangeSlider` to disabled.
I am getting warning in log when setting `slider.setDisable(true);` :

> *Aug 05, 2015 5:40:45 PM javafx.scene.CssStyleHelper calculateValue
>   WARNING: Could not resolve '-fx-disabled-opacity' while resolving lookups for '-fx-opacity' from rule '*.range-slider:disabled' in stylesheet jar:file:/C:/Users/dimitrim/Documents/NetBeansProjects/FlatDesignTest/dist/run546627019/lib/controlsfx-8.40.9.jar!/org/controlsfx/control/rangeslider.bss*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a bug that has been fixed in ControlsFx.  See  https://bitbucket.org/controlsfx/controlsfx/issues/568/cant-set-rangeslider-to-disabled for details

Comment: Thanks, Actually I opened the bug but forgot about this question